Is it a good idea to change one string at a time - Guitar
While reading Guitar maintenance manual of Ibanez electric guitars, I noticed that it recommends changing one string at a time during restringing guitar.
https://www.ibanez.com/world/support/manual/

It does not mention if it's more applicable to Floyd Rose tremolo.
I used to remove all at once and then restring it.
I wonder if there's any recommended way as the manual suggests. Or removing all at once is not a good practice?

Does your guitar have a Floyd Rose?

If there is one broken string, for whatever reason, the it makes sense to simply change that one, providing the set isn't too old, otherwise tone balance will be compromised.
Changing a whole set? Replacing one at a time makes sense, as the tension on the neck will change only a little. Why relieve all the tension, when one can keep it pretty well level while the operation is in progress? It also means that each string can be brought to near enough tension during the process.

Agreed.  For most guitars, it probably would not be worth worrying about too much if you change all the strings at once.  But what would be the advantage?  It's certainly more conservative to avoid as much stress reversal as possible.
